# Custom store action inside ApplicationStore

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing an app that is consuming a [non-standard REST API](http://api.3drobotics.com/swagger-ui/) and I want to consume an endpoint which is [supposed to fetch live data](http://api.3drobotics.com/swagger-ui/#!/mission/staticMap) of a Model my problem is that I would have to either write a $.JSON on the route and push to the Model or add an "action" to the store which is what I'm leaning towards.

I have a Model called "Mission" that is already configured to fetch all or by id from API ( had to write custom adapter and serializer ).

I have a route called Index that is trying to define its model by doing the following:

```
Droneshare.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.live('mission');
  }
});
```

And the contents never get to the controller, but I can see the XHR was made and that missions where loaded on the inspector (see attached images)

[image: http call to fetch live missions]
[image: missions inside the Ember extension]

Here is the source I'm working with, it's not the complete project only the relevant parts: https://gist.github.com/mrpollo/24fd5951c0d7aa95eec2

**Question 1:** What am I missing from my custom action to get this to work?

**Question 2:** Is there a way to not have to redeclare the private functions from store.js inside ember? ([this ones specifically](https://gist.github.com/mrpollo/24fd5951c0d7aa95eec2#file-store-js-L1-L50))

**Question 3:** Would there be another way of doing this?